# Selenium not recognizing actions on JavaScript-generated page

Tags: selenium

O hai SQA, first post here.

I just started using Selenium a few days ago. However, I'm a little stumped getting it to work with one of my projects.

I have an HTML file containing a collection of images. Each image has an event handler, which calls a JavaScript function when I click the image, or press Enter after selecting it with the arrow keys.

However, Selenium doesn't recognize any interaction (mouse clicks or key presses) with the images no matter what I do, although I can get it to work with other sites. The "collage" is JavaScript-generated as opposed to being coded in pure HTML, although I'm not sure if that makes a difference. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Since you have started with Selenium, can you try Selenium 2 (aka WebDriver) API for click operation - http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html

Comment: I have faced an issue similar to this before?  Check out this question: http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/1039/how-do-i-handle-the-login-modal-dialog-created-by-onload-in-a-webdriver-java-b

Answer (score 2):

how is the event triggered? does the element have an attribute say onclick?

another way to trigger javascript is to use the following example, which is more of a workaround.

```
WebDriver driver; // Assigned elsewhere
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("return document.title");
```